# How to reuse a ViewModel in VueJs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I currently have something like this:

```
var items = new Vue({
   el: '#items1',

   data: {
      dataUrl: '/api/data?items=items1',
      items: []
   },

   ready: function() {
      this.getItems();
   },

   methods: {
      getItems: function() {
         this.$http.get(this.dataUrl, function(data) {
            this.items = data;
         });
      } 
   }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="items1">
    <div v-repeat="items">
       <p>{{ name }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to reuse the ViewModel to another HTML part:

```
<div id="items2">
    <div v-repeat="items">
       <p>{{ name }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please notice that the `dataUrl` is different for items1 and items2.

How to do this?

Comment: So you want to use the `items` vm in both divs, but have the URL be different for both? Is that what I'm understanding?

Comment: Yes, but the content of `items` will be different as it will be retrieved from different URL (this is handled by `getItems()`).

Comment: You would have to create a unique ViewModel for each unique HTML `id`. Either that, or you create a Vue.js Component that contains the `<div v-repeat...></div>` element, that contains code that would pull the id from the parent element and call the HTTP request.

Comment: That's what I want to avoid (creating a unique VM for each `id`) if it's possible and supported by Vue, there are 3 sections that have the same behavior like this in one page of my site. Could you share the code for the Vue component in this case? I'm still learning Vue...thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you define and reuse a component something like this:

```
Vue.component("items", {
   template: "#items",
   props: [ "dataUrl" ],
   data: {
      items: []
   },
   ready: function() {
      this.getItems();
   },
   methods: {
      getItems: function() {
         this.$http.get(this.dataUrl, function(data) {
            this.items = data;
         });
      } 
   }
});
```

Template:

```
<script id="items" type="x-template">
    <div v-repeat="items">
       <p>{{ name }}</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

Example usage:

```
<items dataUrl="/api/data?items=items1"></items>
<items dataUrl="/api/data?items=items2"></items>
```

Comment: Is there a typo in template at id=items1 ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It absolutely answers my question above, but I have a bit different case, what if I have a bit different template, like in `items2` block I need to show another field like 'address'. Is the solution similar or do we need different approach? (maybe I should create another question for this).

Comment: You could create a new component with a new template or you could add conditional logic to the template (like a v-if) that only shows 'address' in the appropriate case.